# Does Email Signature extension work on CiviCRM 4.7?

Tags: email

Is anyone successfully using Email Signature extension on CiviCRM 4.7?

https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-signature

Answer (score 1):

Current usage is 8 - that may include some old dev/stage installs by the authors - and almost certainly are 4.5 installs by current CiviCRM users (latest stable release for that extension).

Comment: Could it be that extension still works just fine, but is not tested on CiviCRM 4.7?

Comment: That's not impossible - but it's not likely.

Comment: Curious did you try this extension on 4.7?